# how to get the date from left to right in mysql?

Tags: mysql, calendar, format

what to do, that I get the Date like that **08-06-2017**  and not **2017-06-08** ? in the table of mysql

Because I send the date_value to server like that **08-06-2017**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use 'date_format()' function like 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT([YOURCOLUMNNAME],'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') from [YOURTABLENAME];'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it, it's going to be a mess. First of all the mysql date, date time and timestamp types do not support being stored in different formats. You could however select them with a different formatting, if you wanted to (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). If you absolutely have to store dates in a specific format, you would have to use `text` or `varchar` as type. But then your next problem is going to be ordering and grouping over date fields like that.

My recommendation would be to just stick with the mysql date format and do transformations between the different formats in whatever MVC framework you're using inside the controller or view. That's what they're for. This also leaves you open for the possibility to use different date time formatting based on user locale.

Comment: OK, I let it like before. I just have to format my value before sending it to database : 

`String currentDateAndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());` or any format. realy, easy way (this is java code for example)